# Find the documents whose age is 24 or lives in the state UP

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Sample data

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6068b4d1ba926fd240c5216f"),
    "name": "Amit",
    "branch": "ECE",
    "joiningYear": 2017,
    "language": [
      "Python",
      "C#"
    ],
    "personal": {
      "contactinfo": 234556789,
      "state": "UP",
      "age": 25,
      "semestermarks": [
        80,
        80.1,
        98,
        70
      ]
    },
    "salary": 10000
  }
```

---

Query

```
db.college.find({$or:[{"age":24},{"state":"UP"}]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/mJeXeT-oCe8

Key is `"personal.age"`

As your data is inside `personal` key you have to query inside it.

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "personal.age": 24
    },
    {
      "personal.state": "UP"
    }
  ]
})
```